# TabView change icon on select

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, tabview

I was looking in the documentation of QML but I didn't find anything:

Is there any way to change icon on select into Tab in TabView in QML?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should look to the corresponding style type when you want to customise a control. The detailed description of each control has a link at the bottom:

> Note: You can create a custom appearance for a TabView by assigning a TabViewStyle.

You can then follow [that link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-tabviewstyle.html) and look for the component of the control that you want to customize. In this case, you're looking for the [`tab`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-tabviewstyle.html#tab-prop) property.

Comment: If I use TabViewStyle I can set the same icon to all tab in my TabView

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me? :p

Comment: I'm asking how can I insert different icons to different tabs using TabViewStyle

Comment: Use the `styleData.index` and map it to a list of icons. It depends on what your use case is.